# Is it correct to say "don't pull out your hangnail/ dead skin" or "don't pull off your hangnail/ dead skin"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first 2 pictures show hangnails and the 3rd picture show dead skin.

I think people say "**to pull out hairs**" ([source from dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pluck_1?q=pluck)) because a hair has its root (maybe about 1 or 2% of the hair length) plucked **in** the skin of our head. Because it is  "**in**", so we pull it "**out**".

But do we say "**pull out the hangnail/ dead skin**" or "**pull off the hangnail/ dead skin**"?

For example, "**don't pull out/off your hangnail/ dead skin because you might get your finger bleeding. Leave it alone.**"

Also we have the structure "**get somebody/something + adj.**" (meaning, [to reach a particular state or condition; to make somebody/something/yourself reach a particular state or condition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)) **(1)**

For example, "**He got his fingers caught in the door.**"

And the structure "**get somebody/something to do something**" and "**get somebody/something doing something**" (meaning,  [to make, persuade, etc. somebody/something to do something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)) **(2)**

For example, "**I finally got Michael to talk**" and "**It's not hard to get him talking**".

Is "**you might get your finger bleeding**" a correct expression?

If it is, then which one (1 or 2), does it fall into?

I am not sure if the present participle "**bleeding**" an adjective.

Do we say "**you might get your finger to bleed**"?

Comment: No, we say 'you might _make_ your finger bleed'. To _get_ something to do something usually implies that you want to make it happen.

Comment: @KateBunting, but "**He got his fingers caught in the door.**" implies it happened by chance. Is it possible that "**bleeding**" is an adjective? so that we can say "**He got his finger bleeding**".

Comment: _Caught_ is something that happened to the fingers, not something they did. If the action is intentional, _get_ is followed by a verb in the infinitive or present participle. "My fingers were numb with cold, but I managed to get them to work [or] get them working." "He got his finger bleeding" is not idiomatic, but it would imply that he was trying to make it bleed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not **pull *out*** skin or nails because it is not something that is in the body, but on the body. However, hair is somewhat *in* the head (meaning it is not only on the outside of the head), and that's why you *pull* them out.

**Pull off** is correct when talking about pulling off skin or nails.

**Pull out** is correct when talking about hair, eyes etc. that is in the body.